need help about QlistWidget.data() problem
every single Task Item include Action list I use QlistWidgetItem[] to save it
if I clicked task item. the action view area well reload data from taskitem.data().
when task every single item has no action data when you switch task item the program well not crash.
when there is only one task item with action data won't crash
but when you switch the task item that had action data the program well crash.
enter image description here
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QListWidgetItem

# Important:
# You need to run the following command to generate the ui_form.py file
#     pyside6-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py, or
#     pyside2-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py
from ui_form import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        item1 = QListWidgetItem("task 1")
        item2 = QListWidgetItem("task 2")

        self.ui.listWidget.addItem(item1)
        self.ui.listWidget.addItem(item2)

        action_data_list: List[QListWidgetItem] = []
        action_data_list_2: List[QListWidgetItem] = []
        action_data_list.append(QListWidgetItem("action 1"))
        action_data_list.append(QListWidgetItem("action 2"))

        self.ui.listWidget_2.addItem(action_data_list[0])
        self.ui.listWidget_2.addItem(action_data_list[1])

        item1.setData(Qt.UserRole, action_data_list)
        item2.setData(Qt.UserRole, action_data_list_2)

        self.ui.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.reload)

    # reload item to listWidget_2
    def reload(self):
        current_item = self.ui.listWidget.currentItem()
        action_data_list = current_item.data(Qt.UserRole)
        for i in range(self.ui.listWidget_2.count()):
            self.ui.listWidget_2.takeItem(0)
        self.ui.listWidget_2.clear()
        for action_data in action_data_list:
            self.ui.listWidget_2.addItem(action_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



step one add task item and add three action item for it
only one item no matter how much you click this task item the program won't crash
enter image description here
and step two add second task item and dont add any action item
enter image description here
step three when you selected first task item then boom my pragram already crashed
enter image description here
dont know how to fix it

Please provide a proper [mre].

It looks like you're getting this error when selecting an item. to catch when you select items you can use
if currentItem:
      ....

This way you can make sure whether the item is available (or exsists). Check this in your ActionItemSelected function. Also, qt has most of the slots you use. you are creating unnecessary work for yourself

thx for reply.  def TaskItemSelected(self):  when this function call the program well crash. but problem is it had value. the thing is if self.ui.listWidgetTaskList just had one item no matter how much action item add. the def TaskItemSelected(self): always get proper data. when it comes to two. if you selected other one they must crashed.

this is pyside6 issue switch pyside2 work fine.

Sorry but this answer is completely unhelpful. Also, without a proper MRE it's impossible to give you proper help, and switching to PySide6 might just be a symptom of your issue, which may seem resolved right now, but may pop up again later because of bad implementation.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
